# Why won't bootstrap navbar menu show?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm very new to Bootstrap (and front end dev in general).  I'm trying to get a Bootstrap4 navbar to work.  I've essentially copied and pasted code from the bootstrap website, but I can't get it working.

When I shrink the page, the menu does collapse as it should.  However, when I click on the collapsed menu, nothing happens.  Also, on the expanded menu, nothing happens when I click the dropdown menu.

I've verified path to the boostrap.min.js is correct.

I'm loading this page file via "file://" in my browser, not off a server.  I don't know if that could be a problem, but I wouldn't think so.  Anyway, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script href="static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script href="static/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script href="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure it's something simple (I feel like the javascript isn't loading, for some reason), but I can't figure it out.  Anybody see anything obvious?

Edit: I should also note that I don't see any Javascript errors in console, and I'm not sure I'm checking correctly, but it doesn't look like there are event listeners registered for the button (so nothing *should* happen when I click it).

Edit2: I just started a quick web server to load this from.  None of the javascript files are being requested from the server.  The main problem seems to be with the loading of the javascript files.  Paths are correct, though.

Solved: The problem was I was using href for my script tags, instead of src.  Changed to src and everything is working as expected.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No.  Just added a note about that.  Also, as best I can tell, there aren't any click events registered for the button (nothing shows in the Chromium Event Listeners area of the dev panel)

Comment: You may need to wrap your nav class in a container.
You can add the container before `<nav class=` or after `<nav class=`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The attributes for the script tags were all wrong.  I had href.  It should be src.  I fixed it and everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code below for BootStrap4 Starter template. It will run anywhere just double click on the file. All source included from CDN.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </main><!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```